# Subtitle authoring tool for Ubuntu which supports video playback

Tags: subtitle

I use *GNOME Subtitles* to edit my subtitles. Is there any tool which works with video playback to code subtitles? I saw some screenshots where a subtitle tool has a video running inside it, allowing users to add subtitles easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [gaupol](http://otsaloma.io/gaupol/). You should find it in the software centre, or will be able to install by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gaupol
```

Comment: Thanks. Any chance we can batch translate subs ? Like, using a translation service like Google Translate

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Translating_subtitles#Gaupol_extension

Comment: Not working :(  Redirecting to URL 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/apertium/svn/incubator/gaupol':
A    apertium/apertium.ui.xml
A    apertium/apertium.gaupol-extension
A    apertium/preferences-dialog.ui
A    apertium/README
A    apertium/apertium.py
A    apertium/mode-dialog.ui
Checked out revision 81768.

Comment: @user227495 If this answer was helpful you should accept it. If you have another question then please post another question.

Comment: For the translation part, I would borrow off someone's Windows computer and use [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/). It is simple to operate and translates using Google Translate API (So you don't need local language support).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I don't know how I missed. [Gnome-subtitles](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-subtitles) also have the option to author subtitles based on a playing video.

All you have to do is open a video through Gnome-subtitles

In the **Video** menu, choose **open**

Here is the process in action

[image]